# TTPickerTextField example

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20

I've been trying all day and just can't make the the TTPickerTextField work. It displays, I set its `dataSource` to the example code's `MockDataSource` and type in a name from the mock and it doesn't work. There doesn't seem to be any documentation or any examples anywhere on the internet, something that I find surprising.

So: does anyone have (or can anyone throw together) a really simple example of how the TTPickerTextField works? All I want to do is have someone type something in and put it in a bubble, like in the iPhone Mail app.

Comment: Good question; I hope it gets answered. Three20 is notoriously hard to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen this example?

https://github.com/shayne/TTPickerTextFieldDemo